# laravel MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime class not found

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb

I have mongo database which contain time value like this

> "time" : ISODate("2019-11-28T12:51:38.827Z"),

when I get this value from database using laravel I get it like this

> "time":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1574945497100"}}

I need to convert this value to readable date , I find in the internet solution to use

> MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime

class , but when I apply this code

```
 $utcdatetime = new MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime(1416445411987);
 $datetime = $utcdatetime->toDateTime();
```

I have this error

> Class 'App\Http\Controllers\MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime'  not found

I installed  mongodb driver in my php

```
 php -i | grep -i mongoDB
/etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-mongodb.ini,
 mongodb
MongoDB support => enabled
MongoDB extension version => 1.6.0
MongoDB extension stability => stable
mongodb.debug => no value => no value
```

I don't know why laravel not see this class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put slash before MongoDB

```php
$utcdatetime = new \MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime(1416445411987);
$datetime = $utcdatetime->toDateTime();
```